# Loadtesting - High concurrency = High latency while using Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, load-testing, serverless

I created a lamdba function that fetches a record from DynamoDB.

Now I am trying to get some numbers on the performance of the architecture (Which will be having DAX enabled in a later iteration).

For the test I am using the [loadtest package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest). Below the details of 2 of my tests

### Test #1

#### AWS Lambda Configuration

- Timeout: 30 sec
- Memory: 1024 MB
- Reserve concurrency: 900

#### Test Inputs

- Max Requests:1000
- **Concurrency : 100**

#### Test Result

- totalRequests:1000
- totalTimeSeconds:15.028303200999997
- **meanLatencyMs:1385.2**
- maxLatencyMs:6536
- minLatencyMs:197

### Test #2

#### AWS Lambda Configuration

- Timeout: 30 sec
- Memory: 1024 MB
- Reserve concurrency: 900

#### Test Inputs

- Max Requests: 1000
- **Concurrency : 1000**

#### Test Result

- totalRequests:1000
- totalTimeSeconds:19.298303200999997
- **meanLatencyMs:8648.2**
- maxLatencyMs:18749
- minLatencyMs:832

---

## Questions

1. Why does the mean latency raise so much when change the concurrency level from 100 to 1000 when I have configured the reserve concurrency of the lambda function to run 900 parallel instances?
2. Am I missing any AWS configuration that could improve the numbers ?

Comment: Are you running inside or outside a VPC?

Comment: no i dont configure any VPC

Answer (score 1):

Test 1 has 10x as many requests as concurrent executions, which helps to amortize the cost of any cold starts. On the other hand, Test 2 results are worse because Test 2 is entirely cold starts.

Right now, your tests are not necessarily a fair comparison (depending on what you’re try to measure). You could try repeating Test 2 with the number of requests being 10x the concurrency to see if you still get similar results to Test 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether Lambda was not throttled?
There is a default account concurrency for lambda around <=1000 (which u use in load testing)
Is there any http errors for API Gateway or in Lambda?

AWS :
"AWS Lambda will keep the unreserved concurrency pool at a minimum of 100 concurrent executions, so that functions that do not have specific limits set can still process requests. So, in practice, if your total account limit is 1000, you are limited to allocating 900 to individual functions."

Check :
https://itnext.io/the-everything-guide-to-lambda-throttling-reserved-concurrency-and-execution-limits-d64f144129e5

Comment: there is no errors happen 
i put the 900 reserved concurrency to  the function i use it

Comment: 1.Have you run this experiment only once? Are results consistent?
2.Did you found which lambda execution took that time? Min& Max doesn't say much, as one of the lambdas could have misbehaved and this affected the average
Maybe you can enable X-RAY during execution, it should give some more insights on what takes that time

3.Do you have any other active lambda on your aws account?
Have you selected VPC for your Lambdas?